# Commutator of Position Operator and Generator of Translations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator

**Problem:**

> Let $|\psi' \rangle = \hat T(\delta x) | \psi \rangle$ for infinitesimal $\delta x$, show that $\langle x \rangle'= \delta x +\langle x \rangle$

**Attempt at Solution:**

Using $\hat T(\delta x) = 1-\frac{i}{\hbar} \hat P_x \delta x$ and $[\hat x, \hat P_x] = i \hbar$, I calculate $[\hat x, \hat T(\delta x)]=\delta x$

Therefore,

$$\hat x \hat T(\delta x)=\delta x + \hat T(\delta x) \hat x$$

Plug this into $\langle \psi | \hat T^{\dagger}(\delta x) \ \hat x \ \hat T(\delta x) | \psi \rangle$

$$\langle \psi | \hat T^{\dagger}(\delta x) (\delta x + \hat T(\delta x) \hat x) | \psi \rangle$$

$$\langle \psi | \hat T^{\dagger}(\delta x) \delta x | \psi \rangle + \langle \psi | \hat T^{\dagger}(\delta x) \hat T(\delta x) \hat x | \psi \rangle$$

Since $\hat T$ is unitary, this almost simplifies to the result:

$$\langle \psi | \hat T^{\dagger}(\delta x) \delta x | \psi \rangle + \langle \hat x \rangle$$

**Question:**

What am I doing wrong here? I've seen on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_operator_(quantum_mechanics)#Commutator_with_position_operator) that $[\hat x, \hat T(\delta x)]=\hat T(\delta x) \delta x$, which would solve the problem since

$$\langle \psi | \hat T^{\dagger}(\delta x) \ \delta x \ \hat T(\delta x) | \psi \rangle$$

$$\delta x \langle \psi | \hat T^{\dagger}(\delta x) \hat T(\delta x)| \psi \rangle$$

$$\delta x $$

but I'm really not seeing how to get there with the way Townsend has defined things.

Comment: Which reference by Townsend?

Comment: I'm suspicious of using $\hat T(\delta x) = 1-\frac{i}{\hbar} \hat P_x \delta x$ to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there.  Note that

$$T(\delta x) \delta x = \delta x + \mathcal O(\delta x^2)$$

so if you stick to first order (i.e. consider infinitesimal $\delta x$), your result and the more general result from wikipedia agree.